# Installing docker on azure virtual machine windows 10

Tags: azure, docker, windows-10, hyper-v

I am getting an error upon installing docker on azure virtual machine.

[image]

m/c configuration: azure vm, windows 10 enterprise, Intel 2.4 GHz, 7 GB RAM, 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor.
I went through a few blogs and they asked me to enable nested virtualization on azure vm as follows.

> Set-VMProcessor -VMName MobyLinuxVM -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true

But this also didn't help and the virtual m/c MobyLinuxVM failed to start.
I have installed Hyper-V and Container components from windows features. But the error shows "because one of the Hyper-V components is not running" whereas all the components of Hyper-V are running.
I checked the task manager performance tab and I don't see the virtualization option there. I can't modify the virtualization settings in the BIOS as I am installing docker on an Azure VM. Also I tried disabling the windows firewall but that didn't help.
So how to run docker on azure virtual m/c windows 10 enterprise.

Comment: You could install docker on Azure Windows 10 enterprise. Please ensure you should enable Hyper-V firstly. Virtualization is available on DV3 and EV3 VM. Please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/nested-virtualization-in-azure/

Comment: I test in my lab, it works fine on my Windows 10 VM which sku is `Standard D2 v3`.

Answer (score 19):

Here is a **solution** if you are getting this error on **Azure Windows 10 VM** where you have installed Docker:

> 1. Ensure Windows Hyper-V featutes are enabled by running PowerShell cmdlet:

`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All -Verbose`

> 2. Ensure Windows Containers feature is enabled by running PowerShell cmdlet:

`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Containers -All -Verbose`

> 3. Ensure Hypervisor is set to auto start in the Boot Configuration Database (BCD) by running in **elevated command prompt** the command:

`bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype Auto`

After running all of the above and you **restart the Azure VM**, Docker should be starting normally.

Comment: Docker will try to start by using WSL by default will show up a crash screen on startup. There will be a prompt for switching the back end also. Just close the crash message window and select "Use Hyper-V" when prompted. Docker will be restarted without any issues.

Answer (score 13):

<strike>Azure doesnt yet allow for nested virtualization.</strike>
You need to use DSv3 or E3 instances for that. Just use docker like you normally would

Comment: tested with a Standard D2s v3 (2 vcpus, 8 GB memory), created the VM, installed docker for windows, when prompted to activate hyper-V, selected yes and rebooted. everything was fine

Comment: well, dsv3 were not available at the time of writing so... @CedricDumont

Comment: I had this same problem with D2s_v3. I did not expect it to work, but when I changed it to D4s_v3 Docker started successfully.

Comment: Switching from D2s_v3 -> D4s_v3 worked for me as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft offers images with preinstalled docker enterprise. This works even on a B2s VM. Just select any of the "Microsoft Server 2019/2016 Datacenter with containers" image while creating the VM.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above use DSv3 or E3 instances. in case it doesn't work for you, check for security type while creating Azure Virtual Machine, Now a days it 'Trusted Launch Virtual Machine", switch it back to Standard and install docker as usual. It should be working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while installing Docker Hub on Azure Win 10 VM, but i find vary easy fix to this.

1. Make sure the VM you are choosing is supported by nested virtualization. Here I used D4s_v4 (4vCPU and 16GB Ram).
   [Description Of D4s_v4 VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAH8E.png)

2.While Creating the VM make sure you have change the security type to **"Standard"** from **"Trusted Lunch Virtual machines"**
[Security Type Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TYih.png)

3. Also make sure that you've enabled the Hyper-v , Windows Subsystem For Linux and etc. etc. you found till now on google....