# Is it possible to use Docker in the windows Data Science vm from azure?

Tags: azure, docker, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I got a Data Science VM in Azure with Windows and i tried to install Docker in it but it doesnt work. I read some articles which say, nested VM is only possible in DSv3 or E3 instances (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44817200). 
But I also read, that it is possible in other VMs though (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/malte_lantin/2017/08/03/using-gpu-powered-virtual-machines-in-the-cloud-for-your-machine-learning-and-deep-learning-workloads/). Can anyone clearify that?

When I installed docker in the DataScience VM I got an Hyper-V error and I was unable to start Hyper-V. The error code says, that there is not enoug storage but I got 50 GB free!
So I guess, that it might be a problem with the VM itself.

Comment: so which VM SKU (size) did you use? DSv...?

Comment: I'm using the NC6 VM with 56 GiB RAM and 1x K80 GPU, @silent

Comment: See the answer below, only certain SKUs support nested VMs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need one of Dv3 or Ev3 series virtual machines to have the feature of nested virtualization. Nested virtualization is a feature that allows you to run Hyper-V inside of a Hyper-V virtual machine (VM).

Ref:

[How to enable nested virtualization in an Azure VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nested-virtualization)

[Nested Virtualization in Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/nested-virtualization-in-azure/)

Comment: Also certain F and M series VMs SKUs are capable of nested virtualization: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/acu